# Optaplanner score corruption with constraint stream

Tags: java, optaplanner, vehicle-routing, timefold

I'm getting a score corruption with quite a simple example:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Score corruption (-4850000soft): the workingScore (-19init/0hard/0medium/-4850000soft) is not the uncorruptedScore (-19init/0hard/0medium/0soft) after completedAction (Standstill 1 {null -> Vehicle 1[0]}):
Score corruption analysis:
  The corrupted scoreDirector has 1 ConstraintMatch(s) which are in excess (and should not be there):
    optimiser.allocation.solver/Project minimum weight delivered/[Project 1, 150000]=0hard/0medium/-4850000soft
  The corrupted scoreDirector has no ConstraintMatch(s) which are missing.
```

The uncorrupted score is incorrect, as the soft score should be much closer to 150000 for the first step of construction.

My model is almost the same as the example VRP, but with projects added as a planning fact. Each standstill has a project associated with it.

I originally built the constraint stream around the standstills, which was simpler, but it was missing the projects with no standstills, so the new constraint stream is as follows:

```
protected Constraint projectMinimumWeightDelivered(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    // A project must deliver at least the minimum weight
    return constraintFactory
            .forEach(Project.class)
            .filter(project -> project.getMinimumWeightToDeliver() != null)
            .join(Standstill.class, equal(project -> project, Standstill::getProject))
            // Only count standstills that have a real vehicle
            .filter((project, standstill) -> standstill.isPickup() && standstill.getVehicle() != null && standstill.getVehicle().isReal())
            // group by project, sum weight of standstill
            .groupBy((project, standstill) -> project, sum((project, standstill) -> standstill.getWeight()))
            .filter(Project::hasNotDeliveredMinimumWeight)
            .penalizeConfigurable(Project::amountUnderMinimumWeight)
            .asConstraint("Project minimum weight delivered");
}
```

The constraint stream seems to give the correct values when all the standstills are initialized, but running in `FULL_ASSERT` mode revealed this error. I have disabled all other constraints to replicate this, along with a couple of custom shadow variable listener classes I was suspicious of.

Is there a clear issue with my constraint stream implementation based on how optaplanner calculates the incremental scores?

Comment: After some testing, it seems it's a problem during initialization: I believe when there are no standstills initialized for a project, the `join` is not matching to any standstills and so is basically filtered out there. What I'm not sure how to do is handle this case.

Comment: Whether or not a joiner matches something should not cause score corruptions. Join is a safe operation. I understand this is a problem for modelling your domain and needs to be addressed (look in the CS docs, there are examples how to make joins match uninitialized entities), but it is most likely unrelated to the score corruption.

Comment: @LukášPetrovický any tips where to start with the domain? I have vehicles with a standstill list as a planning list variable, and standstill with some shadow variables (inverse relation for vehicle, previous and next). There's some custom shadow variable listeners for arrival time details, but the error persists with it all disabled.

Comment: The hint in the error (`Maybe a score constraint doesn't select all the entities it depends on, but finds some through a reference in a selected entity.`) makes me thing that `filter((project, standstill) -> standstill.isPickup() && standstill.getVehicle() != null && standstill.getVehicle().isReal())` might not be getting the correct vehicle? I don't completely understand how this should be accessed if so.